# two c files and returning value from a file to another file

Tags: c, file, external, cross-compiling

I have two c file. 1) aaa.c 2) bbb.c

bbb.c file calculate the line numbers of data file (data.txt).

Then, I want to include line number calculated in bbb.c into aaa.c.

For example, in aaa.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define ROW "linenumber"
```

in bbb.c,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("bond.txt", "r");
    int ch;
    int count =0 ;
    do
    {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if(ch=='\n') count++;
    }while(ch != EOF);

    return count;
}
```

I would like to use the value (count) calculated from bbb.c to that linenumber in the "#define Row "linenumber"".

How can I do that and how to compile aaa.c and bbb.c toghether?

Comment: A macro is only visible in the [translation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) it is defined in.

Comment: Are both files separate programs? Or are they linked into a single program?

Comment: Well, both files separate programs as you see aaa.c bbb.c. However, I would like to link them into a single program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible you can declare variable in bbb.c and use extern in aaa.c file to tell the compiler and it makes local to that file.

In aaa.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern int linenumbers; 
int main() {
  ...
}
```

bbb.c

```
 int linenumbers;
```

The variable must be declared global in bbb.c and extern in aaa.c should also be a global.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Edited. It cannot be local rather global variable.

Comment: bbb.c need to be calculate line number of data.txt. For example, data.txt file contains 10 lines, the linenumber goes into the aaa.c.

Comment: @ChangWoonJang Once the global variable in bbb.c has the value of 10 it externed to aaa.c which when you access it from aaa.c you will find it is 10.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do requires 2 times compilation. You can of course create a build script which will build a project with bbb.c, run executable, remember the number, parse the aaa.c and put this number instead of ROW, and finally recompile both files - but what for?

If your logic requires that the number is valuing on run time, just use ROW at run time  - I suppose it is smth with allocation of arrays, allocate memory with malloc. No reason to make things so complex.